# Netbeans cannot recognize TODO items in .cu file

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans to develop CUDA but it seems that Netbeans cannot recognize the TODO items in `.cu` file. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Team > Action Items` and add the comment syntax for `.cu` file.